# Disabling images in Chrome/Firefox (ie, using “text mode”)

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

Is there an extension or setting for Chrome or Firefox that can disable images in a web page so that I can have a text-only view? Changing the settings in *Under the Hood* is too cumbersome.

Comment: -1 for a question that states that [the right answer](http://kb.iu.edu/data/acpv.html) is "too cumbersome" and so asks for wrong answers to replace it.

Comment: With the built-in settings, I can't selectively view webpage with and without image at the same time. How is that asking for a wrong answer?

Comment: That isn't the question that you have written.

Comment: @JdeBP, you are completely missing the point to extensions and addons. They are meant to enhance the browser to make things easier and provide supplemental functionality that the base browser does not. There is *nothing* wrong with asking if there is a way to make something more accessible, otherwise there would not be so many [extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search?category=ext&q=button) that provide a button to get at things that usually require more clicks, or [work on an API](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=71067) to make content-settings easier to access.

Comment: That isn't the question written either, Synetech.  Read what was actually written before you changed it, too.

Comment: Other than spelling and capitalization, I changed *nothing* in the content of the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So far, all I could find was [this extension for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/image-block/) that lets you block images, and [this extension for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/epdedalbkhcbhcmcpfglmhngjpgimcmm) that lets you block images and other content.

(There may also be a [userscript](http://userscripts.org/scripts/search?q=toggle%20images), but I have yet to locate any generic one, but there is [one specifically for Wikipedia](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/61977).)

Several months ago, I [requested](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=74324) a button/method to make toggling content easier, and it turns out that a month earlier, [work was started](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=71067) on a way to create an API to allow extensions to do exactly this, so if you can wait, one day there will be an extension that can do specifically what you want.

For April Fool’s day 2011, Google released a Chrome extension called [*ChromeLite*](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromelite/bjekedpipaedojkbialnhabcecmfpofh) which while meant as a joke, actually *does* display most websites in text-mode. Since then, others have created similar extensions like [*Text Mode*](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/text-mode/adelhekhakakocomdfejiipdnaadiiib) and [*Text Only, Please!*](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/text-only-please/jdfpkfddmojhlcoepfpdileleloickfj).

[image: Screenshot of “ChromeLite”]

Comment: does this load whole content then block images or does,t load images at all??

Answer (score 2):

For every browser, there exist Extension AdBlock (also, there exists Adblock Plus) - 
[For **Chrome**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom?hl=en); 

[For **Firefox**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/);

[For **Opera**](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/adblockforopera/);

 After instalation, on the right upper corner (along with address bar) there appears an icon. right click on that >Settings> Edit filter> and add these lines

```
*.gif
*.png
*.jpg
*.bmp
*.swf
```

and click Save. 
after this, the images+flash files wont be loaded on sites, but if you want to temporarily enable for specific site, then while you are on that site(page), click the icon and clcik **Dont run on this page** (or pause). then you can again re-enable.

Anyway, there exist other several extensions to disable image load :

**for Firefox** : 1) Image Block; 2) ImgLikeOpera (for image blocking) + FlashBlock (for flash blocking) 

**for Chrome** : 1) [**HideShowImgs**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hideshowimgs/delbndpnablebhjofgcplkkiadolmbdi?hl=en); 2) [**Text Mode**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/text-mode/adelhekhakakocomdfejiipdnaadiiib)

**for Opera** : Click CTRL+F12>Pages>Images>Dont load, also enable Opera turbo from left bottom corner.

Comment: Thanks ! For Adblock Plus, click on its icon (next to the url bar), click "Options", go to the tab "Add your own filters", and add one by one the filters (*.gif, *.png, etc.).

Comment: an example: for this https://www.nytimes.com/2018/01/28/business/energy-environment/oil-boom.html add these filters: nytimes.com##.media
nytimes.com##.button
nytimes.com##.newsletter-signup
nytimes.com##figure
nytimes.com##.related-combined-coverage
nytimes.com##.site-index
nytimes.com##.supplemental-items
nytimes.com##footer
Other syntaxes: https://adblockplus.org/filter-cheatsheet
Use the inspect element tool to find the class name (##element-ID.class-name)